# A nested array is changing to a string of values going from JavaScript to Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, openlayers

Using OpenLayers (although I think this is a JS/Rails issue) I draw a box,

```js
var source = new VectorSource();

function addInteraction() {
  var draw = new Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Circle',
    geometryFunction: createBox()
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
  draw.on('drawend', function(event) {
    var boxCoords = event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
    console.log(" boxCoords: ", boxCoords);
    document.getElementById('year_snippet_extent').innerHTML = boxCoords;
  });
}

addInteraction();
```

Console log output (the four corners of the rectangle, but returns to beginning, that's how OpenLayers handles drawing boxes, i.e. it's a polygon):

```
 boxCoords:  
 [Array(5)]
 0: Array(5)
 0: (2) [977.8497980044467, 710.486212043731]
 1: (2) [1341.059647947079, 710.486212043731]
 2: (2) [1341.059647947079, 754.3238572469668]
 3: (2) [977.8497980044467, 754.3238572469668]
 4: (2) [977.8497980044467, 710.486212043731]
```

What get's written to `year_snippet_extent` a field on the edit form: `977.8497980044467,710.486212043731,1341.059647947079,710.486212043731,1341.059647947079,754.3238572469668,977.8497980044467,754.3238572469668,977.8497980044467,710.486212043731`

I want to save this to Postgres as an array. Postgres datatype is text [], Rails datatype is the same although my migration was array, `add_column :years, :snippet_extent, :text, array:true`.

The field in edit is `<%= form.input :snippet_extent, label: 'Automatically filled when snippet is drawn' %>`

What is reformatting the array? Or should I use a different approach?

I couldn't figure out how to have `box_coords` saved to `snippet_extent` directly, so came up with this work around. I could parse what is saved for my purposes, but thought I should be able to make this work right.

Here's what I wrote to get what I think is the correct format (I only need the lower left and upper right corners):

```
 var minx = Math.round(boxCoords.[0].[0].[0])
 var miny = Math.round(boxCoords.[0].[0].[1])
 var maxx = Math.round(boxCoords.[0].[2].[0])
 var maxy = Math.round(boxCoords.[0].[2].[1])
 var snippetExtent = "{[[" + String(minx) + "," + String(miny) + "],[" + String(maxx) + "," + String(maxy) + "]]}"
```

Not that hard but I was hoping not necessary. I'm rounding to make it easier to read and the precision is meaningless.

Comment: Yes, you've discovered that an Array Object is not an HTMLString. But since the JavaScript engine knows this too, it does the best it can to interpret your intent: it stringifies your array for you. If you want a specific format, the best approach would be to provide a string where one is required.

Comment: So I need to parse the array and make it whatever string I want? That's what I did originally, but then I had to "unparse" it to use it and that seemed like a lot of trouble since Rails, JavaScript and Postgres knows about arrays. But if that's what JS wants!

Comment: The first thing to understand with client/server computing is that they are not directly connected. They need a communication protocol (several actually) to assist moving information from client to server. That protocol is HTTP - Hyper_TEXT_ is what the protocol transfers. With that background, the one understands that data structures on the client must be serialized to strings before being sent using the protocol. it is also understood that the text must be translated back into the appropriate data structure at the other end. JavaScript and Ruby use the same tooling: `JSON.*`

Comment: Thanks. That's a good reminder. Rails and JavaScript have a lot of magic and it only goes so far. I'm rewriting it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using leaflet, but we are doing something quite similar: upon drawing a geometry we show a modal with a form, and we set a hidden text field to contain the geometry.

We are using postgis, so we immediately store the geojson representation in that hidden field. Not quite sure if that is possible using OpenLayers (pretty sure it is, just not finding it right away). But maybe that is not the easiest format for you? If you are using postgis and activerecord-postgis gem, you can just assign a geojson to a geometry.

But if not, you will have to parse a geojson yourself (which is not too hard, but definitely a little more complicated).

So, as mentioned in the comments: JSON is a much better exchange format, always used in API's as both JS and Rails handle it very well.

So in your JS you could write:

```
document.getElementById('year_snippet_extent').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(boxCoords);
```

and at the rails end you would convert it back to whatever was put it into it as follows:

```
box_coords = JSON.parse(params[:year_snippet_extent])
```

Comment: Randy Casburn: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and particularly thanks to @nathanvda for specifics. I had lots of refactoring to do since I'd made such a mess trying different things. Also had to create a replacement column as :json. When I get it all working I'll show the solution although it's pretty much what's above. BTW the storing in (hidden) field is just JS and Rails. I have PostGIS installed because I thought I'd need it, but so far have used with Postgres. I should give PostGIS a go though.